# How to unit test Double Tap in TapHandler?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, qml

I am trying to unit test a QtQuick TapHandler:

**TapHandlerUnderTest**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls


TapHandler {
    required property ApplicationWindow appWindow

    onDoubleTapped: {
        console.warn('double tapped')
        appWindow.toggleMaximized()
    }

    onSingleTapped: {
        console.warn('single tapped')
    }

}
```

**Test Case**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtTest


Item {
    id: testHelper
    width: 400
    height: 400

    property bool toggleMaximizedCalled: false

    property var appWindow: ApplicationWindow {
        function toggleMaximized() {
            testHelper.toggleMaximizedCalled = true
        }
    }

    TapHandlerUnderTest {
        id: objectUnderTest

        appWindow: testHelper.appWindow
    }

    TestCase {
        name: "TapHandlerUnderTest"
        when: windowShown

        function cleanup() {
            testHelper.toggleMaximizedCalled = false
        }

        function test_tap_data() {
            return [
                { taps: 2, called: true, tag: '2x' },
            ]
        }

        function test_tap(data) {
            mouseDoubleClickSequence(testHelper)
            compare(testHelper.toggleMaximizedCalled, data.called)
        }

    }

}
```

**What did I try?**

1. I tried using a [mouseDoubleClickSequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-testcase.html#mouseDoubleClickSequence-method). The test is failing with the following log:

```
QWARN  : qmltestrunner::TapHandlerUnderTest::test_tap(2x) qml: single tapped
QWARN  : qmltestrunner::TapHandlerUnderTest::test_tap(2x) qml: single tapped
FAIL!  : qmltestrunner::TapHandlerUnderTest::test_tap(2x) Compared values are not the same
   Actual   (): false
   Expected (): true
```

2. I tried using two [mouseClick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-testcase.html#mouseClick-method) functions instead of the [mouseDoubleClickSequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-testcase.html#mouseDoubleClickSequence-method). I got exactly the same result as in (1).
3. I tried using the [touchEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-testcase.html#touchEvent-method). That leads to no output - it does not even recognize a single tap this way.

**Is this a bug or how can we test a double tap (double click) here?**

I am setting `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` for my test cases but I tested it with different platform settings. It did not change anything.

Best regards,
Elias

Comment: A simple solution (workaround?) would be to refactor a method, say actionDoubleTapped(). Then unit test merely invokes that method directly. e.g. `TabHandler { onDoubleTapped: actionDoubleTapped(); function actionDoubleTapped() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: You should add the touchEvent code that you tried.

Comment: @StephenQuan Could you add this as an normal answer so that I can accept it? Yes, it is a workaround but it's a rather clean one :)

Comment: @Mitch I tried several different approaches. None of them gave me any result. I started with the official example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-testcase.html#touchEvent-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer as requested.

A simple solution (workaround?) would be to refactor a method, say `actionDoubleTapped()`. e.g.

```
Page {
    TabHandler {
        onDoubleTapped: actionDoubleTapped()
    }

    function actionDoubleTapped() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then unit test merely invokes the `actionDoubleTapped` method directly.